# ASP MVC view added with ajax - isn't visible in browser page source

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

This problem drive me nuts for two days.
I have strongly typed view with text area. User can write comment in that area. After button click I save comment and return view from action method with comment id and comment text. Returned view I add to div called "messages" and it works. Comments saved, View returned, Display fine but when I right click in browser for page source **div "Messages" is empty**.
This thing makes me problem. Each comment has edit button and if there is 5 comments in messages div when I click edit I got edit function called 5 times. But when I hard code HTML with comments in div messages it works. But when I ajaxify page nothing works as it should.
Here is the code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#addMessageForm').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {                    
                    $('#messages').prepend($(result).fadeIn('slow'));                    
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddMessage", "Comment", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "addMessageForm" }))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.CommentText);
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
}

<div id="messages">
</div>
```

This is add comment Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddMessage(CommentModel model)
        {
            model.Author = "Vlada Vucetic";

            Random r = new Random();
            int n = r.Next(1, 1000000);

            model.CommentId = n;
            return View("CommentView", model);
        }
```

[image]

This is what happen when I click edit button. But as I said when I add hard code comment div in div messages and click edit it called only once. I have no idea what is happen here? Why page source doesn't display anything in browser...

[image]

This is comment view. This is what I add to div messages.

```
@model Demo_AjaxPosting.Models.CommentModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<script src="../../json2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $('.editButton').live('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var container = $(this).closest('div');  //$(this).closest('.commentWrap');
        var itemId = container.attr('id');
        alert(itemId);
        var nestId = '#' + itemId;

        var txt = $(nestId + ' #commentTextValue').text();

        $(nestId + ' #commentTextValue').remove();
        $(nestId + ' #editButton').remove();
        $(nestId).prepend('<textarea id="editArea">' + txt + '</textarea>');
        $(nestId).append('<input type="submit" value="Ok" class="btnOk" />');
    })
</script>

    <div style="border: 1px solid #dddddd;">
        @Html.ActionLink(@Model.Author, "SomeAction") @Model.CommentId
        <div class="commentWrap" id="@Model.CommentId">
            <p id="commentTextValue">@Model.CommentText</p>
            <a class="editButton" href="#">Edit</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The page source shows the page as it is initially received from the server. From the source, the DOM is created and displayed. If you later add comments to the DOM (using jQuery), it will be displayed but the page source isn't updated. So far, that's the expected behavior. Regarding your "Edit" links: Please show the source of the "CommentView" and the associated Javascript code. That's where you problem probably is.

Comment: I can't tell from your question where exactly the edit button handler code is. But my guess is the code is run every time you dynamically add a comment. That way you would end up having three event handlers installed on each of the three edit button. That would explain why it is run three times. The correct way is to install the event handler once when the page is initially loaded from the server.

Comment: The last code. Bellow the images. $('.editButton').live('click', function (e) { ... is event when I click on edit button.

Comment: The last piece of code consists of two parts: the first line installs the event handler and the remaining lines are the event handler themselves. Now my question basically is: when is the first line run? Once when the page is transmitted or every time a new commend is added?

Comment: I put it between 'script' tags. I don't attach it specifically when new comment is added. After every new comment new CommentView is returned. I updated that last code in question with complete page (CommentView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page source shows the page as it is initially received from the server. The DOM is created from the source and displayed. If you later add comments to the DOM (using jQuery), it will be displayed but the page source isn't updated. So far, that's expected behavior.

If you want to inspect the HTML after comments have been added, use a tool like Firebug. It works on the DOM and nicely handles dynamic parts.

The reason your event handler is executed several times is that you add it several times. Every time a comment is added, the Ajax answer transmits (and the browser executes) a script with the following line:

```
$('.editButton').live('click', function (e) {
```

As a result, you end up having several event handlers installed. They might have identical code. But that doesn't matter. They are installed several times. So if you click the "Edit" link, several of them are executed and you get several text boxes.

The solution is to move the Javascript code (including the SCRIPT tags) out of the *CommentView* and into the view of the main page.

Comment: Dishhh... I really need to spend a little more time in learning client side programming. Thanks :)